# Acumatica API get all attachments

Tags: api, soap, acumatica

I have a problem while trying to get attachment from ACUMATICA through API service.
As the example in http://acumaticaopenuniversity.com/pdf/T210_Acumatica_Web_Services.pdf page 36

[Example code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrkJ7.png)

But I don't know how many files here and what are their names? How can I get all attachment of this entity?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The contract based web service API has a straightforward GetFiles interface for getting all files of an entity. When you don't have special requirements that forces you to use the screen based web-service API, I'd recommend you use the contract based one.

Interface:

```
File[] GetFiles(Entity entity)
```

Usage pseudo-code:

```
using (DefaultSoapClient soapClient = new DefaultSoapClient())
{
    soapClient.Login("username", "password", "CompanyLoginName", null, null);

    File[] files = soapClient.GetFiles((Entity)soapClient.Get(new Entity { EntityIntField = new IntSearch { Value = 1 } }));
}
```

Contract based web service API reference:

http://acumaticaopenuniversity.com/courses/i210-contract-based-web-services/